# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-data-services

I am getting this error in a WCF web service when the program attempts to use a method that employs the entity framework. However, we know that the server has the entity framework (correct version) installed because it is hosting another WCF web service and an intranet site that use it successfully.

I've tried to set `copy local` to `true`, however this simply compiles the Entity Framework dll into the debug/release folder of the project that uses it, not the web service project that gets deployed (the project that gets deployed contains a references the project that uses the entity framework).

Has anyone run into this kind of issue before and know a work-around either with or without using `copy local`?

Comment: When you deploy your app you need to deploy EntityFramework.dll as well. EntityFramework.dll is meant to be bin deployed. Before EF6 it required core EF component - System.Data.Entity.dll - which does live in GAC. For EF4.x and EF5 EntityFramework.dll contains only DbContext API, CodeFirst, (and newer versions also Migrations) and the rest is in System.Data.Entity.dll (which is on the machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to simply place the EntityFramework.dll and .xml file generated in the bin of the project that uses the Entity Framework and place that in the bin of the service project that was being deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the Application Pool for the IIS Site in question is set to use to correct .NET Framework version. In the case of EF 4.1, the Application Pool should be running on .NET Framework version 4 or higher.

To identify the version of .NET being used by the site, first find out the Application pool in use (in IIS, click on Basic Settings for the site), then identify the appropriate pool under the Application Pools node. The .NET Framework version should be listed.

Comment: Before we knew what the problem was this was something we checked about two/three/four times. Verified that it was .NET 4+

Comment: Hmm - you shouldn't need to copy local either way since this DLL should already be in the GAC...

Comment: EntityFramework.dll should not be in GAC. Only System.Data.Entity.dll should be GAC'ed. EntityFramework.dll is meant to be bin deployable. They are probably not copying the EntityFramework.dll with their app to the server.

Comment: @Pawel: Right now we are testing out setting `copy local` on the project that uses the entity framework and copying the .dll/.xml files into the bin of the project we deploy. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: @NealR I would think that if you have a reference to the EntityFramework.dll in the project the dll should be automatically copied to the output dir along with all other dlls you are uilding. I don't know how you deploy your app but basically you need to make sure that that the EF.dll is copied along with all other dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether bit versions are compatible between entity framework and server. If the server is 64 bit and you are using 32 bit entity framework dll you can get this error. Then change app pool setting to enable 32 bit applications.

Comment: EntityFramework.dll is a pure IL/AnyCPU and should work in both 32-bit and 64-bit processes without issues.